# Как обойти X-CSRF-Token

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Хочу пропарсить `input` и хочу вытащить значения `value` но при запуске программы он показывает мне

[image: токен]

А по идею должно вывести

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'http://192.168.1.104:11080'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("input"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сигнатура метода find(): [find(name, attrs, recursive, string, **kwargs)](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

Метод возвращает словарь, из которого нужно взять значение по ключу `value`, поэтому, чтобы сработало, используйте:

```
x_csrg_token = soup.find('input', name='X-CSRF-Token')['value']
```

Comment: Судя по второй картинке, автору нужен не X-CSRF-Token